# Add a 5 min timer between execution of each function

Tags: google-apps-script

Suppose I have a function as given below. I am facing a problem of Exceeding maximum execution time. This is because function a,b & c are executing one after the other without giving google server a breathing space. I want to give that breathing space so that maximum execution error doesn't occur. To do that I would like to give it a 5 mins delay between execution of each function a,b and c in this case.

```
function main(){

a();
b();
c();

}
```

The above function should work like this:

```
function main(){

a();
rest for 5 mins before executing the next function
b();
rest for 5 mins before executing the next function
c();

}
```

I can't figure out how to achieve this?

Comment: Five minutes is not necessary.  You just need to stop before timeout and then start again at the same point and starting at the same point is probably the hardest part.  It's possible that just a few changes to your code could resolve your issue but we can't really help you with such a cryptic code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. That error message is not related to how busy google app script is but to the total execution time being exceed by your main function.

In other words, your main function is taking more time than the allowed for a execution in app script, regardless of what you are doing in that function.

The solution then is not to add sleep or idle times since that will make the situation even worse.

The only solutions to expand the time limits are:

1. Create a trigger to run every N minutes and develop a system to track what to execute next (if something is not already running). It could be using the built-in cache or even a google sheet tab to maintain that internal system status.
2. Programmatically create and remove triggers, so that when function A starts, you can remove a trigger (code) to avoid future executions and when it ends you can create it (code) to run the next step. Once again, you need a way to maintain the internal system status.

Comment: Very helpful tips - this lead me to the right direction. I have removed the main function. Now I only have function a and b. Function a runs initially, and returns a variable x. Function b is then needed to run manually with this variable x in place using a trigger after function a ends. How can I achieve this? I believe I am close to cracking this. I liked ur idea of using Google sheets itself to keep track of the variable x that function a, and function b will be returning. The main thing is, I will need to somehow get the latest variable x they will be returning and and then run the functio

Comment: Update on the above comment: I 99% figured it out. I am updating a row with the latest iteration. I reduced it all the way to just one function which is getting the values from this row. Now I need to find a way that when the value in the row A1 changes, function a() triggers automatically. How do I approach this?

Comment: Update; I Figured it out 100% :). Thank you so much!! I added a time trigger on the one function! And it worked like magic!!

Comment: Great work, that design is key to overcome the execution time limit and I have used it many times. I am glad you were able to complete it by yourself.

You can accept the answer if that helped you to solve the question.

Comment: Hi, I have accepted :D. Thanks once again! Also, is there any way to reduce the time trigger by less than 1 min? Or.. is there any way to run this function a again as soon as it ends? like an onedit function in a row--> as soon as function changes that variable x in this row --> onedit triggers? However I have read that onedit cannot work on programmable triggers, it needs to be done manually by a user, please correct me if I am wrong? Or have I reached the maximum efficiency I could get with appscript?

Comment: That is a hard limitation, as far as I know. I think that is the best solution possible so far.